# Store Each Numeric Value in an Array to a Variable in VBA in PowerPoint

Tags: arrays, vba, powerpoint

I have an array:

```
For iCtrl = LBound(chkboxes) To UBound(chkboxes)
   PriorityList = Array(chkboxes(iCtrl).Tag)
Next
```

This looks through the Tag properties of checkboxes stored in a user form. Basically, from this I can get the text stored within the Tag properties for all the checkboxes that are checked. (These are just numbers from 1 to 16.)

What I need to do with these numbers is store each number to a variable. Only 3 three checkboxes can be checked at once, so I would have these variables: var1, var2, var3. The lowest number would be stored as var1, the highest number would be stored in var3, with the middle number in var2.

I assume there has to be a simple solution for this, but I have been wracking my brain and have had no luck. I am a beginner at programming, so that may have a lot to do with it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub GetLowestChecked3()
    Dim var1 As Long, var2 As Long, var3 As Long, t As Long
    var1 = 999: var2 = 999: var3 = 999
    For iCtrl = LBound(chkboxes) To UBound(chkboxes)
        If chkboxes(iCtrl).value = True Then
            t = CLng(chkboxes(iCtrl).Tag)
            If var1 > t Then
                var3 = var2
                var2 = var1
                var1 = t
            ElseIf var2 > t Then
                var3 = var2
                var2 = t
            ElseIf var3 > t Then
                var3 = t
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!!